# What are the leaves that are connected to a rose stem called?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm wondering what the leaves that are part of a rose is called. Not the petals, but the little green leafy things that are connected to the stem.

Are they leaves? Blades? Petals? What?

Comment: I've always called them "leaves".

Comment: I assume you're talking about [*sepals*](http://www.flora.dempstercountry.org/Flower.Glossary.html). But this is General Reference, not "use of English".

Comment: Do you mean the sepals or the bracts?  Either way, try http://gardening.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This is certainly a specific of English vocabulary, but it is off-topic because it is a technical/scientific term that you could find by looking up flower biology.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually they are called sepals.